# Is it possible for my app/server to create a Google Calendar event on behalf of 2 people in order for them to privately meet via a Google Meets link?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-meet

In my NextJS React app, a meeting needs to be booked between 2 people.  Ideally, `User A` will have to accept a meeting request from `User B`, and then I'd like a Google Meets link to be created and shared with both `User A` and `User B`'s respective e-mails.  It seems this is not possible - what I am gathering is that I need OAuth 2.0 in order to generate a Calendar event to further create the Google Meet link.  Can my app do this in the backend or does the app need to get `User A`'s permission in the front end first via OAuth so that it can be created?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create event we must take user's consent via OAuth authentication(User A in your case) using [Google OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) which we have to do by the interaction with the user(i.e. in the front end).

Once the authentication is done then you can create google calendar event with conference data in User A's calendar using [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert) and add User B as the attendee of the event so that the calendars will be booked for both User A and User B. Make sure to add sendUpdates as query parameter to send the notifications. Conference data in google calendar event will generate google meet link.

Please refer the official documentation to learn more:
[Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert)